# angular extend controller methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularJs I have a bunch of controllers with some funktions they are same:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(...){

    function lockForm(id){
        ...
    }

    function releaseForm(id){
        ...
    }

    function dbError(e){
        ...
    }

    // and some other little stuff again and again in every controller
}
```

The examples I've read are all based on extending (mixin) stuff from $scope and @this. Is'nt there a way to extend the whole controller as is?

With thanks to [Shushanth Pallegar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4229768/shushanth-pallegar) I solved my Problem. It's not exactly what I wanted but way better than before.

```
// base ctrl
angular.module('myApp').controller('baseViewCtrl', function ($scope, viewData) {

        this.lockForm = function() {
            viewData.isLoading = true;
        };

        // ... and others

});


// child ctrl
angular.module('myApp').controller('childCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var viewData = {
            // some stuff
        };

        // inject from basecontroller
        angular.extend(this, $controller('baseViewCtrl', {$scope: $scope, viewData: viewData}));

        // link $scope
        $scope.viewData = viewData;
        $scope.onSelectUnit = onSelectUnit;

        // child controller methods
        function onSelectUnit(){
            this.lockForm();
            ...
        }
});
```

It looks a bit ugly at all because I avoided @this nearly everywhere

Perhaps I go this way and use base instead of @this to make it more clear that there are injected methods:

```
// child ctrl
angular.module('myApp').controller('childCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var viewData = {
            // some stuff
        };

        // inject from basecontroller
        var base = $controller('baseViewCtrl', {$scope: $scope, viewData: viewData});

    // link $scope
    $scope.viewData = viewData;
    $scope.onSelectUnit = onSelectUnit;

    // child controller methods
    function onSelectUnit(){
        base.lockForm();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Put common functions in a service and inject service. Controllers should be very lean. Business logic belongs in services

Comment: You can use parent controller and child controller concept.Or else you can use also service/factory feature.

Answer (score 3):

Use $controller service and pass the name of the controller you need to extend as below

**parent controller**

```
  angular.module('myApp').controller('parentController',function(){

     $scope.lockForm = function(id){
        ...
    }
  });
```

**child controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('childController',function($controller){

    var parentController = $controller('parentController',{$scope:$scope});

     console.log(parentController.lockForm);

  });
```

refer [$controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller)

in-order to extend to `this` , use as below

```
angular.module('app').controller('childController',function($controller){

    var parentController = $controller('parentController',{$scope:$scope});
     angular.extend(this,parentController);

     console.log(this.lockForm);

  });
```

If your using functions with attaching those to scopes your need to return those functions as below.

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('parentController',function(){

         var _lockForm = function(id){
            ...
        }

       return{
          lockForm = _lockForm
       }

      });
```

so in your extended controller could use as below

```
 var extendedController = $controller('parentController',{$scope:$scope});

    extendeController.lockForm('123');
```

Comment: I see. But whats with the closure of the imported methods (or better named functions)?

Comment: @Steffomio you have return your function and used them . I have updated the answer with this regrad !